# Is the current in a transformer core due to the B field or is it the other way around?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm currently learning the full equivalent circuit for a real transformer, and there is a parallel reactance which apparently is due account for a magnetizing current that is used to create the actual B field in the core. But I had always thought the B field in the core was created by the AC current in the primary coil. So now my current understanding is that somehow some of this AC current in the primary coil moves into the core and this creates the B field which then creates an eddy current in itself. But I have no idea how the primary AC current can somehow magically jump into the transformer core? Please help correct my understanding.

Comment: Can you give your references?

Answer (score 1):

$\let\om=\omega \def\bB{{\bf B}} \def\bH{{\bf H}} 
\def\bdl{{\bf dl}} \def\bE{\bar E} \def\bI{\bar I} \def\bV{\bar V} 
\def\D#1#2{{d#1 \over d#2}}$
To answer your question I need to enter transformer physics, perhaps in a more detailed way than you have seen. So excuse me for length.

I'll deal with a much idealized transformer, with no losses. Then we have two windings on a common magnetic circuit. It isn't true that

> the B field in the core is created by the AC current in the primary coil.

Magnetic field is always due to both primary and secondary currents, $I_1$, $I_2$.

I'll assume currents are slowly varying in time (usually in a
sinusoidal way, but this is of no interest for now). Magnetic field is computed using Ampère's law:
$$\oint \bH\cdot\bdl = \sum I.\tag1$$
If primary winding has $n_1$ turns, secondary has $n_2$, the total
concatenated current is
$$\sum I = n_1\,I_1 + n_2\,I_2.$$
As to LHS of (1) I'll take a closed line running within the iron core and will assume $\bH$ has the same intensity everywhere. Then
$$\oint \bH\cdot\bdl = l\,H$$
and we get
$$H = {1 \over l}\,(n_1\,I_1 + n_2\,I_2).$$
Of course $\bB=\mu\bH$, with $\mu$ much larger than $\mu_0$, usually a few thousand times.

---

To compute induced emf we need to know the flux $\Phi$, but that's easy. I'll assume that no line of magnetic field exits from iron so that flux concatenated with each single turn is
$$\Phi = B\,S$$
where $S$ is the iron sectional area. We'll have to consider total
concatenated fluxes to both windings:
$$\eqalign{
    \Phi_1 &= n_1 B\,S = 
      \mu\,{S \over l}\,n_1\,(n_1\,I_1 + n_2\,I_2) \cr
    \Phi_2 &= n_2 B\,S = 
      \mu\,{S \over l}\,n_2\,(n_1\,I_1 + n_2\,I_2).\cr}$$
These are usually written
$$\Phi_1 = L_1\,I_1 + M\,I_2 \qquad \Phi_2 = L_2\,I_2 + M\,I_1$$
where
$$\eqalign{
    L_1 &= \mu\,B\,S\,n_1^2 \cr
    L_2 &= \mu\,B\,S\,n_2^2 \cr
    M &= \mu\,B\,S\,n_1\,n_2.\cr}$$

*Note*: There are useful relations
$${M \over L_1} = {L_2 \over M} = {n_2 \over n_1}$$
$$M = \sqrt{L_1 L_2}$$
only holding when there is no *stray field*, as we assumed. Otherwise a coupling coefficient should be introduced.

---

We are now ready to write the main equations for induced emf's:
$$\eqalign{
    V_1 &= -\D{\Phi_1}t = -L_1\,\D{I_1}t - M\,\D{I_2}t \cr
    V_2 &= -\D{\Phi_2}t = -L_2\,\D{I_2}t - M\,\D{I_1}t.\cr} \tag2$$
If currents and emf's are sinusoidal functions of time we write (as usual)
$$V_1 = \bV_1\,e^{j \om t} \quad \rm etc.$$
Then (2) become
$$\eqalign{
    \bV_1 &= -j\,\om\,L_1\,\bI_1 - j\,\om\,M\,\bI_2 \cr
    \bV_2 &= -j\,\om\,L_2\,\bI_2 - j\,\om\,M\,\bI_1.\cr} \tag3$$
Eqs. (3) are our main result, which we'll use to understand your
question.

Let's assume for a moment that secondary is open, whereas primary is connected to an external generator of emf $\bE$. Then $I_2=0$ and $\bV_1$ is kept fixed by the generator: $\bV_1+\bE=0$. Eqs. (3) say
$$\eqalign{
    \bE &= j\,\om\,L_1\,\bI_1 \cr
    \bV_2 &= -j\,\om\,M\,\bI_1 .\cr}$$
At secondary terminals an emf $\bV_2$ appears:
$$\bV_2 = -{M \over L_1}\,\bE = -{n_2 \over n_1}\,\bE.$$
(the minus sign is due to our initial choice for $I_1$, $I_2$). Since the only current is $\bI_1$, it's true in this case that magnetic flux in the iron core is due to primary current. Note that $\bI_1$ is $90^\circ$ behind of $\bE$ so the same happens to $H$ and to $\Phi$.

If the secondary is closed on a resistor $R_2$ secondary current no longer vanishes: $\bV_2=R_2\,\bI_2$. From eqs. (3)
$$\eqalign{
    \bE &= j\,\om\,L_1\,\bI_1 + j\,\om\,M\,\bI_2 \cr
    R_2\,\bI_2 &+ j\,\om\,L_2\,\bI_2 = -j\,\om\,M\,\bI_1.\cr}$$
By eliminating $I_2$ we get
$${\bI_1 \over \bE} = 
    {1 \over j\,\om\,L_1} + {L_2 \over L_1\,R_2} =
    {1 \over j\,\om\,L_1} + {n_2^2 \over n_1^2}\,{1 \over R_2}.
  \tag4$$
Eq. (4) shows the equivalent primary circuit: there are two impedances in parallel, the primary inductance and the load secondary resistor reflected to primary by the square of transformer ratio.

The meaning is that the transformer draws from generator *two* currents:

- the magnetization current (equal to the open-circuit current)
- the load current.

I leave for you to verify that 
$${I_2 \over \bE} = -{n_2 \over n_1}\,{1 \over R_2}$$
i.e. that in the secondary equivalent circuit there is a generator of emf $-n_2\bE/n_1$ (for sign see above) and the load resistor.

So you see that the primary current has two components $90^\circ$ out of phase:

- one is devoted to create the magnetic field and is independent of transformer's load
- the other is committed to producing current in the load and only
  depends on its impedance.

The magnetic effect of the latter is exactly compensated by that of secondary current.

I think the above should answer your question.